# I have to show no proper intermediate fields exist between $Z_2$ and $GF(2^3)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to show no proper intermediate fields
exist between $Z_2$ and its overfield $GF(2^3)$, Can any one help?

Comment: Have you tried computing the degree of the extension?

Comment: Hint: 3 is prime.

Answer (score 0):

It is a theorem on finite fields that for any prime $p$, and any positive natural numbers,
$$\mathbf F_{p^{\scriptstyle r}}\subset \mathbf F_{p^{\scriptstyle s}}\iff r\mid s.$$